# Find the determinant

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, determinant

I am trying to find the eigenvalues of a matrix and I cannot remember how to find the determinant of $A-\lambda I$:

\begin{equation}
\pmatrix{1-\lambda& 2& 1 \\
         2& -\lambda & -2 \\
         -1& 2& 3-\lambda}
\end{equation}

I know the rules for finding the determinant of an $m \times n$ matrix.

1. $\det A = -\det A'$ when switching a row
2. $\det A = \det A'$ when performing the replacement row operating
3. $\det A = \dfrac{1}{\lambda}\det A'$ when scaling a row

Then I row reduce until I have a diagonal matrix...

Do I have to use the above rules or is there a simpler way?
I am not looking to use the formula for a $3\times 3$ matrix. I am looking for a more general solution so that I will be able to solve this problem for a $4 \times 4$ matrix or $5 \times 5$ matrix.

Comment: Does this help [**Det of $nxn$ Matrix**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determinant#n-by-n_matrices) and [Examples](http://ltcconline.net/greenl/courses/203/MatricesApps/determinants.htm)?

Comment: For a $4 \times 4$ or larger matrix, unless there is special structure that makes it easy, finding the determinant by hand is really a waste of time.  Use a computer algebra system or Wolfram Alpha: e.g. http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=characteristic+polynomial++[[+1%2C+2%2C+1]%2C+[2%2C+0%2C+-2]%2C+[-1%2C+2%2C+3+]]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The standard way to calculate the determinant of small matrices manually is the Laplace expansion: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_expansion#Examples

Answer (score 0):

My favorite method for finding $3\times3$ determinants is shown [here](http://youtu.be/ROFcVgehEYA).  For larger matrices, you'll have to resort to the more general formula given in the Wikipedia article on determinants.

Comment: He wanted a general approach, not just $3\times3$.